# Как подружить PHP с консолью Google Chrome?

Tags: отладка, google-chrome, php

У меня такой вопрос - можете поэтапно объяснить как мне, к уже существующему проекту подключить  PHP Console server library (https://github.com/barbushin/php-console#php-console-server-library)? Задача - нужно просматривать все ошибки PHP в Хром консоли. Как это лучше сделать? Возможно, Вы посоветуете другое решение... Очень рассчитываю на Вашу помощь!

Comment: А в чем сложность то? Там же вроде автолоадом загрузка идет, не?

Comment: Там человеческие видео, подробные инструкции и примеры выложены. Куда уж проще? Установить расширение для хрома(PHP Console extension), скачать архив(Download .zip) и закинуть в проект, подключив require_once('../src/PhpConsole/__autoload.php');

Comment: http://phpdebugbar.com/ - лично мне нравится эта штука. Не пользуюсь, но нравится.